# Want to create a Facebook app for auto share posts on the wall

Tags: wordpress, facebook, publish

Ok, this is the deal. I just launched a website working on Wordpress where users can register, either from the site or by a facebook account, and share videos and images with the community.

What I want to do now is to create an application that lets user to publish their posts automatically on their facebook walls, if their accept the request of course.

I was looking on google for days and I didn't find anything. This is freaking me out!

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

> **Publishing**
>
> You can publish to the Facebook graph by issuing HTTP POST requests to the appropriate connection URLs, using an access token. For example, you can post a new wall post on Arjun's wall by issuing a POST request to https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed:
>
> ```
> curl -F 'access_token=...' \
>      -F 'message=Hello, Arjun. I like this new API.' \
>      https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed
> ```
>
> The Graph API reference provides [more detailed information](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) on the supported arguments and their corresponding values.